# Unable to decrypt a file with the public signature

Tags: openssl

I got this signature

```
openssl verify cert.pem
cert.pem: C = US, O = Apple Inc., OU = Apple Certification Authority, CN = Apple Root CA
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

Looks good.
I got this file, but it then tells me it cannot open the file with this command

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in receipt2.hex.pkcs7 -pubin -inkey cert.pem -out verified-data.bin
unable to load Public Key
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you encrypting (can't be done with public certificate), or checking a signature (can be done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cert.pem` is a certificate. A certificate *contains* a public key, but it *is* not a public key. You need to extract the public key from the certificate.

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -pubkey -out pubkey.pem
openssl rsautl -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem …
```

Alternatively, use `pkeyutl`, which has two benefits: it also works on other public key schemes (e.g. ECDSA), and it has an option to extract the public key from the certificate.

```
openssl pkeyutl -certin -in cert.pem …
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, will test and tick the green box if it solves my problem!